# Viability of Updating/Writing Data to Excel from hundreds of Text files

Tags: excel, text-files, vba

I was looking for some advice as to the viability of frequently Updating/Writing Data to Excel from hundreds of Text files.

I am running a task management database in excel-VBA-PowerPivot etc (cos we are not allowed access :S). For the latest use of this solution there are multiple users needing to update different parts of the spreadsheet no doubt simultaneously. To get around the read only lock issue (shared workbooks arent an option) I was thinking of having a text file in each task's folder (on the network). Then write code for the bulk of updates(often from outlook) to be done to the individual text files within each task's folder and then write code in the workbook to frequently update all the data from all the text files. If this solution lasts for a few years it could end up with up to 1000 text files to update.

Before I implement this I was hoping I could get advice as to if this would be viable. Mainly seeking advice as to if reading data from a text file on a network is a very resource intensive task? Because if so and if it took >15mins to update the data I would go in another direction.

Sorry if this is long winded and thanks in advance for the knowledge sharing.

Comment: This concerns me: `If this solution lasts for a few years it could end up with up to 1000 text files to update` How about using a database and giving people the ability to update it? You can use ADO to populate from it (Which you could also use to populate from Text files but again I wouldn't recommend it)

Comment: Thanks Dan, Any tips on how to set up a database that can be updated by multiple users simultaneously without MS Access?

Comment: Thats a program best answered by your IT group, if they can give you an SQL server then that would be ideal but otherwise you could use an Access database. I am personally against Access as a DB solution simply because of the amount of maintenance required (Compacting and repairing the DB every so often) but in your case it may be useful. You will then need to work out how to interact with the DB, obviously your users can't write SQL bulk inserts so maybe some sort of pretty layer on top or some VBA code to restrict what can and can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

### Option 1: MS SQL

First of all the best way would indeed be to setup a common MS SQL Database which users could update directly as mentioned in the comments above (e.g. via Access).

### Option 2: VBA

Otherwise your idea with separate text files (csv or maybe xlsx) with records to update from is perfectly feasible and shouldn't take as much time to execute. The bottleneck would rather be the network bandwidth rather than the VBA code itself. Some ideas to consider:

1. You will probably need to traverse your network directory for these files. [This post might be of help](http://analystcave.com/vba-dir-function-how-to-traverse-directories/).
2. If you want to do updates, deletes and inserts using XLSX files (easier to work than txt/csv) **go for MS Query in Excel** (Ace OLEDB). From VBA you can run an INSERT or UPDATE like below. Otherwise writing the necessary code will take ages and be error prone

*Example:*

```
INSERT INTO [Sheet1$]  SELECT * FROM `C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.xlsx`.[Sheet1$]
```